# Passing CSV Headers into a drop down menu in a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, drop-down-menu

I am trying to take the first line of a CSV file, and display the fields in a single drop down menu.

The CSV (users.csv) looks like this:

```
Email,Firstname,Lastname
test@test.com,Test,Testerson
test1@test.com,Test1,Testerson1
test2@test.com,Test2,Testerson2
test3@test.com,Test3,Testerson3
```

I have already passed the first line into an array with the following code.

```
<?php
 if(($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $arrHeader[] = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
    }       
print_r ($arrHeader);
?>
```

I now want to pass that array into a single drop down menu, so the only options on the menu will be Email, Firstname and Lastname.

When I try to pass these values straight into the menu, obviously I get a conversion error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

I tried the following already, and was met with an Array to String conversion error.

```
<?php
 if(($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $arrHeader[] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    }   
foreach($arrHeader as $arr1)
    {
        echo '<option value = "' . $arr1. '">' . $arr1 . '</option>';
    }  
?>
```

Comment: You should write a `foreach` loop that puts each element of `$arrHeader` into an `<option>` tag. What did you try?

Comment: Before I asked this question I tried the foreach loop in the below answer and was met with an error.

Comment: We can't tell what you did wrong if you don't show your code.

Comment: @Harvey do not write "I have an error". Post the error message too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array will be
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Email [1] => Firstname [2] => Lastname ) )

So Try

```
$arrHeader = $arrHeader[0];       
foreach($arrHeader as $value=>$title){       
echo '<option value = "' . $value. '">' . $title. '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Added select tags before and after the foreach, worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `implode` function, eg. someting like this

```
echo '<option>' . implode('</option><option>', $arrHeader) . '</option>';
```

but you probably would like to have `value` attribute too, so a loop would be better:

```
foreach($arrHeader as $text){
  echo '<option value = "' . $text. '">' . $text . '</option>';
  }
```

**EDIT**

If you'd like to assign column number consider using:

```
foreach($arrHeader as $key=>$text){
  echo '<option value = "' . $key. '">' . $text . '</option>';
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.
I already tried passing the values straight into a dropdown, and I was met with an Array to string conversion error.

Comment: Use `$arrHeader = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");` instead of `$arrHeader[] = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");`